# How do you apply a custom theme to a custom route in React Admin?

Tags: react-admin

So I'm passing a custom theme into `<Admin />`, which works great for `<Resource />`s and `loginPage`. However, the theme is not applied to components that are included in `customRoutes={customRoutes}`. How can I do this?

```
const theme = createTheme();

<Admin
  {...providers}
  loginPage={LoginPage}
  history={history}
  theme={theme}
  customRoutes={customRoutes}
>
  <Resource
    name="organizations"
    list={OrgList}
    create={OrgCreate}
    edit={OrgEdit as any}
  />
</Admin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like wrapping `<Admin />` with a `<ThemeProvider />` is a solution to this.